# jQuery 1.8 find event handlers

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-1.8

How to find event handlers on an object in jQuery 1.8+?

```
var func = function(){ alert(1); };
var obj = $('#obj');
obj.on("click", func);
// obj.data('events') is undefined
```

Comment: seems like a good question, you can test it on this js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/968jj/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the data function [as is done by jQuery internally](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/).

On previous versions, you could call it like for other data :

```
obj.data('events');
```

In jQuery 1.8, [this direct access was removed](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10589), so in recent versions you must call it like this :

```
$._data(obj[0], "events")
```

You can see it in action by opening the console in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8TpeP/2/

Comment: Thank you. Learned it today. Only knew the pre 1.8 method till now.

Answer (score 5):

to find event handlers of an element in jQuery 1.8+ you've got to do this way:

`$._data($("YOUR-SELECTOR-HERE").get(0), "events")`

Comment: or briefly: `$._data($("YOUR-SELECTOR-HERE")[0], "events")`