# Checking if jQuery .hover action is already binded

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Is there any way to check if an element already has an action, triggered by jQuery .hover function?

Comment: There is no documented way to do it that doesn't use internal methods that are subject to change from version to version.

Comment: There's no easy way to do that, but you can check `$._data( elem, "events" );` and see if mouseenter/leave has been bound.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236067/test-if-event-handler-is-bound-to-an-element-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it by checking `element.data('events')['eventName']`

In case of hover, it will be:

```
var hasHover = x.data('events')['mouseover'] && x.data('events')['mouseout'];
```

In jQuery 1.8 and later, you must access it using `$._data` as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12214688/921204)

i.e.

```
var events = $._data(obj[0], "events");
var hasHover = events['mouseover'] && events['mouseout'];
```

Comment: Unless you're using jQuery 1.8+, where it has been moved elsewhere.

Comment: @KevinB - Ahh, didn't know that detail. Been using the above technique for a couple years now. But yes, I been using versions <= 1.7.2

Comment: @KevinB - Another SO answer solves it for versions >= 1.8

Comment: It's still using undocumented methods that shouldn't be used for much more than debugging.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the filter on the selector

```
$('.result').each(function(){
$(this).hover(function() {
$(this).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
'height':'110px',
},160);
},function(){$(this).animate({'height':'38px'},80);});
});
```

Comment: ah i missed your question sry