# How can I get all window events in JQuery 1.9?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have recently upgraded JQuery to version 1.9. On version 1.4, I was doing something like this:

```
     var windowEvents = $(window).data("events");
     if (windowEvents.unload.length > 0) {
          // some fun stuff
     }
```

Of course, in jQuery 1.8 this ability was removed. After some research, I found a suggestion for getting around this:

```
     var windowEvents = $._data($(window), "events");
```

But, according to the console, windowEvents is undefined. What am I doing wrong? Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this work `$(window).data('__events__');`?

Comment: I wouldn't write code that relies on undocumented features, like event handlers being stored in a particular location.

Comment: Have you bound any handlers to the window ?

Comment: Can you describe why you're using that check? What is the fun stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are still stored in the same place. But it stores only events that have been bound, and only after at least one is bound (*otherwise `data()` will return `undefined`*) .

So you will have to change your condition

```
var windowEvents = $(window).data("events") || {};
 if (windowEvents.unload && windowEvents.unload.length > 0) {
      // some fun stuff
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems to work for me with `$._data` if the event handler is bound :

```
$(window).on('unload', function() {
   // do stuff
});

if (($._data( window, 'events' ).unload || []).length) {
    console.log('unload is bound');
}else{
    console.log('unload is NOT bound');
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EfQUw/)

Answer (score 2):

I found solution on http://dbj.org/dbj/2013/04/09/list-of-jquery-events/

it's base is:

```
/* (c) 2013 by DBJ.ORG, GPL/MIT applies */
jQuery.events = function (expr ) {
  var rez = [], evo ;
   jQuery(expr).each(
      function () {
         if ( evo = jQuery._data( this, "events"))
           rez.push({ element: this, events: evo }) ;
     });
 return rez.length > 0 ? rez : null ;
}
```

To use it just call:

```
jQuery.events("div");
```

Where div is place for any jquery selector. I've tried it on jQuery 1.9 and it work very well for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up including a check to see if windowEvents was defined. In addition I included the [0] when asking for the events (this solution was found here: [jQuery 1.8 find event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214654/jquery-1-8-find-event-handlers)). So the final code looks like this:

```
var windowEvents = $._data($(window)[0], "events");
if (windowEvents && windowEvents.unload.length > 0) {
    // some fun stuff
}
```

This is now functioning as it did before the upgrade. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's great, but you really shouldn't wrap the window in jQuery just to get the native window back with `[0]`, just do window, like in my example, which does exactly the same as your code, only cleaner.