# jQuery find event handler(s) for this object on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

jQuery 1.11.2

Yes, I'm aware that it's been answered a couple of times before - but the provided replies doesn't work for me.

Using this page:
https://www.lensway.se/cart

I need to check if any events have been added to the "Lägg till linser"-button.
[image: Button to get events for]

I use the solution from here:
[jQuery 1.8 find event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214654/jquery-1-8-find-event-handlers)

```
jQuery._data($('.add-row.LENS.btn.gray')[0], 'events')
```

But that returns undefined.

I know it has events, because I can see them in Chrome Dev Tools:
[image: Showing available events]

The actual code that's executed to add the code looks like this:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".add-row", function(a) {
```

(I have no control over the code so I can't make modifications to it, I just need to detect if that code has been run and the element has the event)

Comment: But maybe it is not jQuery events !

Comment: Yes it is, as you can tell from the screenshot from Chrome Dev Tools above.

Comment: I can also add my own test event just to see if it's caught and it still returns undefined: $('.add-row.LENS.btn.gray').on('click', function eventTest(){alert('OK!')})

Comment: Scratch that. I AM able to catch my own added jQuery events, but already added jQuery events aren't shown.

Comment: @jBoive may be you are trying to log it before any event attachements.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

The event wasn't actually set on the object it was set on the document for some reason:

```
$(document).on("click", ".add-row", function(a) {
```

That's why the data object was empty (I was looking at the wrong element).

Comment: Please accept your answer to (finally) resolve this question.