# JQuery check events binding

Tags: jquery, events, binding

I need to check if some events are already bound on an element.

For example

```
$(".animate").click(function(){
    alert('Here comes action');
});
```

and

```
$(".someOtherSelector").click(function(){
    alert('some other action');
});
```

HTML

```
<a class="animate"></a>
<a class="someOtherSelector animate"></a>
```

In second function I need to check if there is an event already bound on this element. If so it should not execute `alert('some other action');`.

I'm using jQuery version 1.10.1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to obtain a list of events bound to an element in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729732/is-it-possible-to-obtain-a-list-of-events-bound-to-an-element-in-jquery)

Comment: Actually i saw this question already. But in 1.10.1 $(".someOtherSelector").data('events') returns null. And if i using $(this) it returns null too

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214654/jquery-1-8-find-event-handlers) which explains how to do it on recent versions.

Answer (score 4):

As of **jQuery 1.8**, the `event data` is no longer available for **data**. Read this [jQuery blog post](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/08/building-a-slimmer-jquery/). You should now use this:

```
jQuery._data(element, "events")
```

**Code**

```
$('.someOtherSelector').each(function(){
    console.log($._data(this, "events"));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G3pDj/)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '_data'

Answer (score 2):

you can get the events `$(".someOtherSelector").data('events')`, then check if the required event is present or not.

```
​var events = $._data( $(".someOtherSelector")[0], "events" );
if(events.indexOf("click") == -1) {
  $(".someOtherSelector").click(function(){
    alert('some other action');
  });
}
```

Comment: This was removed long before 1.10.

Comment: Ohh sorry i missed `using Jquery v. 1.10.1`

Comment: Tnx but $(".someOtherSelector").data('events'); returns null

Comment: @LeoRay Can you give a try to modified one.